# Git acusa que diretório ignorado tem conteúdo modificado

Tags: git

Tenho o conteúdo diretório no meu arquivo `.gitignore`, da seguinte maneira:

```
app/dir/*
```

Porém quando dou um `git status`, o git acusa o seguinte:

```
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   app/dir (modified content, untracked content)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

No meu entendimento, ele nem deveria saber ou ligar se há conteúdo modificado dentro desse diretório, já que ele deveria ser ignorado. O que esse status quer dizer, e como resolver isso?

Comment: dir é um submódulo? `git status --ignore-submodules` retorna a mesma mensagem?

Comment: Hm, eu tinha certeza que não era um sobmódulo (não me lembro de ter criado), mas rodando esse comando vem "working directory clean"

Comment: Posso simplesmente apagar o .git que tem dentro desse diretório? Acabei de descobrir esse arquivo lá.

Comment: eu examinaria o conteúdo de `.git/config` antes de apagar o diretório. A seção `[submodule "app/dir"]` deve conter o url da onde você clonou o conteúdo de `dir`. Aqui tem a receita para apagar um submodulo https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial#Removal

Comment: Obrigado, @MarcosBanik. Não quer postar isso como resposta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa mensagem pode aparecer caso `dir` seja um submódulo do seu repositório. Você pode conferir isso executando `git submodule` no seu repositório raiz.

Caso vc queira que `git status` ignore as alterações em `app/dir` execute `git status --ignore-submodules`.

Caso prefira remover o submódulo, primeiro investigue o conteúdo de `app/dir/.git/config`. Se ainda quiser remover `app/dir/.git` você também terá que editar editar os arquivos `.git/config` e `.gitmodules` do repositório raiz.

Comment: Só uma observação: não havia nada liga a submódulos no meu `.git/config`, nem existia um arquivo `.gitmodules`. Tive de rodar `git rm --cached app/dir` para remover o lixo que sobrou.